# How to send data from table to popup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I create popup for create and edit data. Now datasource in popup is "xxxx (create)" . I want to send value from clicked table row and show those value in pop up for data edit purpose.

---

This page use to pass data on clicked table row.

[image]

---

This page use to display retrieved data from table row for edit data.

[image]

And now I can get record id and I can log data in this record but data is not show in popup

Comment: That is because your form datasource in your popup is set specifically to create mode only. If you need a create only form due to validation as well as an edit form I would suggest putting two forms in the popup for each of those purposes and toggling their visibility based on edit row button click or similar.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa Thank you so much. Now I can create 2 forms in the popup and I can change the visibility of each form.

Comment: @midtonight? Has this been solved?

Comment: @GNUsNotAUser Yes, the problem is now resolved.